# Why doesn't this code with a lambda expression work in .NET Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, delegates, c#-2.0

The following code is not working in .NET Framework 2.0.

```
public delegate string MethodInvokerWithStringResult();

public string NameInvoker()
{
    if (InvokeRequired) 
    {
        return this.Invoke(new MethodInvokerWithStringResult(() => lblName.Text));
    } 
    else 
    {
        return lblName.Text;
    }
}
```

How do I convert this to work in .NET Framework 2.0?

Comment: Whenever you say "is not working" or the equivalent, **please** post what that means. Did you get an exception, compiler error, incorrect/missing results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# 2 did not have lambda expressions. It does have [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) via the delegate syntax:

```
public string NameInvoker()
{
    if (InvokeRequired) 
    {
        return this.Invoke(new MethodInvokerWithStringResult(delegate { return lblName.Text; }));
    } 
    else 
    {
        return lblName.Text;
    }
}
```

It is also fairly common to avoid repeating code in both a delegate and the method:

```
public string NameInvoker()
{
    if (InvokeRequired) 
    {
        return this.Invoke(new MethodInvokerWithStringResult(NameInvoker));
    } 
    else 
    {
        return lblName.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this code in visual studio 2012(target framework 2.0).it is working fine. but when I use this code in Visual studio 2005(target framework 2.0) I get following error "Error 2 'MethodInvokerWithStringResult' is a delegate type and requires a single 'addressof' expression as the only argument to the constructor.

Comment: My requirement is framework 2.0. and I'm using vb.net. here I posted a C# version of same code

Comment: @fihsak Because Visual Studio 2005 uses an older compiler.

Comment: @fihsak If you wanted to know about VB.NET then why didn't you ask a question about VB.NET?

Comment: @fihsak AFAIK VB.NET did not support anonymous methods/delegates until the version that came with .NET Framework 3.5 (VB 9). You will have to use something like my second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. [Annonymous Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx):

   ```
   public string NameInvoker()
   {
       if (InvokeRequired) 
       {
           return this.Invoke(new MethodInvokerWithStringResult(delegate { return lblName.Text; }));
       } 
       else 
       {
           return lblName.Text;
       }
    }
   ```
2. A named method (regular method which answers the delegates signature):

   ```
   public string NameInvoker()
   {
       if (InvokeRequired) 
       {
           return this.Invoke(new MethodInvokerWithStringResult(NamedMethod));
       } 
       else 
       {
          return lblName.Text;
       }
    }

    private string NamedMethod()
    {
         return lblName.Text;
    }
   ```